# Can I import a TypeScript class from my own module to global?

Tags: typescript

I have a class in a module.

```
module Foo {
    export class Bar {

    } 

    /* Some more interfaces and classes to be used only in this module */
}
var bar = new Foo.Bar();
```

This class is for a library, and I don't want other users to write Foo.Bar but just Bar to use my Bar class:

```
var bar = new Bar();
```

I can do this by defining a new variable Bar.

```
var Bar = Foo.Bar;

var bar = new Bar();
```

However, now I have a problem. I cannot use the Bar as a TypeScript type identifier.

```
function something(bar: Bar) { // Compiler: Could not find symbol 'Bar'.

}
```

I can also solve this problem by defining a new class that extends Foo.Bar.

```
class Bar extends Foo.Bar {

}

var bar = new Bar();
function something(bar: Bar) {

}
```

However, the resulting Bar class is not exactly same with Foo.Bar, as `Bar === Foo.Bar` and `Bar.prototype === Foo.Bar.prototype` both returns `false`.

I tried to find a method using TypeScript module feature such as import and require, but it seems I cannot do this with them. Is there any good method to expose my Bar class to global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Instead of

```
interface Bar extends Foo.Bar {
}
var Bar = Foo.Bar;
```

You can simply do :

```
import Bar = Foo.Bar;
```

## Complete Example :

```
module Foo {
    export class Bar {
        x: number
    } 

    /* Some more interfaces and classes to be used only in this module */
}

import Bar = Foo.Bar;

var bar = new Bar();
function something(bar: Bar) {

}
```

Comment: Much simpler! This is what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: Oops. Resulting d.ts file now does not includes Bar as global class object. Hmm...

Comment: The d.ts problem seems to be fixed in the new compiler. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/346
Anyone who uses current version 1.1 compiler should add `import Bar = Foo.Bar;` line in d.ts file by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this works as intended.

```
module Foo {
    export class Bar {
        x: number
    } 

    /* Some more interfaces and classes to be used only in this module */
}
interface Bar extends Foo.Bar {
}
var Bar = Foo.Bar;

var bar = new Bar();
function something(bar: Bar) {

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want/need a module at all, just export the class:

```
class Bar {
   x: number;
}

/* Some more interfaces and classes to be used only in this module */

export = Bar;
```

and then in the consuming code:

```
import Bar = require('./Bar');
var bar = new Bar();
```

Comment: This method seems to require users use 'require'. This is not a problem, but I prefer to make things simplest and `import Bar = Foo.Bar` was what I exactly want! Thank you for answering :)