# Imported classes does not appear on d.ts file

Tags: typescript

This is related to this question: [Can I import a TypeScript class from my own module to global?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861405/can-i-import-a-typescript-class-from-my-own-module-to-global)

I have made a module and I want to expose a class to the global scope.

```
module Foo {
    export class Bar {
        x: number
    }

    /* Some more interfaces and classes to be used only in this module */
}
```

At first, I made an interface and defined a new variable to achieve this.

```
interface Bar extends Foo.Bar {
}
var Bar = Foo.Bar;
```

The generated JavaScript had my Bar as a variable.

```
var Foo;
(function (Foo) {
    var Bar = (function () {
        function Bar() {
        }
        return Bar;
    })();
    Foo.Bar = Bar;
})(Foo || (Foo = {}));

var Bar = Foo.Bar;
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

The d.ts file included my global Bar interface and variable.

```
declare module Foo {
    class Bar {
        public x: number;
    }
}
interface Bar extends Foo.Bar {
}
declare var Bar: typeof Foo.Bar;
```

Then, **I noticed that I can simply use `import` to expose my class**, and I did so.

```
import Bar = Foo.Bar;
```

The resulting JavaScript file was exactly same.

```
var Foo;
(function (Foo) {
    var Bar = (function () {
        function Bar() {
        }
        return Bar;
    })();
    Foo.Bar = Bar;
})(Foo || (Foo = {}));
var Bar = Foo.Bar;
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

However, my d.ts file now does not include any information about the global Bar.

```
declare module Foo {
    class Bar {
        public x: number;
    }
}
```

Is this an intended result? I think this would cause errors, as it would allow declaring variables with the same name, when I include the JavaScript file and d.ts file in other project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug in current compiler, and new compiler seems to have fixed this. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/346

Corrected declaration:

```
declare module Foo {
    class Bar {
        x: number;
    }
}
import Bar = Foo.Bar;
```

Comment: consider using minimal examples next time, we do not need translation of TypeScript code either.

Answer (score 0):

When you use an import statement, the compiler assumes that the definition is elsewhere.

For example, if you imported something from `fileA.ts` into `fileB.ts`, the generated `fileA.d.ts` would already contain the declaration, which would then conflict with `fileB.d.ts` if it also included the declaration.

So I would say that this behaviour is intentional.

Comment: Wouldn't fileA.d.ts have its declaration within its own module? Maybe `ModuleA.ClassA`. fileB.d.ts would have it on global scope, maybe just `ClassA`. I think the declaration of `ModuleA.ClassA` and `ClassA` should not conflict with each other.